# What does the wishbone symbol mean?

Tags: voltage, schematics, wire, diagram, symbol

I'm looking at a schematic where various wires connect to blocks.
Sometimes the blocks have a wishbone symbol with a number next to it.
Other times, it's a wishbone symbol without a number.

I've been unable to find the correct name for this symbol to learn more about it.
What does it mean?

[image]

Possibly unrelated, but why do the above blocks have dotted lines, while the one below does not?

[image]

Comment: pin & socket , guess which is which

Comment: A lot of the time, dotted lines making a box on a wiring diagram can mean the segregated area is in a different are or place. This could mean inside a cabinet in the same area as the rest of the drawing, or in a completely different location to the rest of the drawing.

Comment: For the second question, it looks to me like the connector mate to P331400 is not defined at this drawing level. I would guess it mates into a pcb or some ots part. Whereas the J/P50025 are both defined at that drawing level.

Answer (score 2):

pin & socket interfaces are shown with

- "> and >"  or
- "< and < "  with interface showing type by intuition or
- in this case socket and pin number
- where J is for Jack , now unisexually called Receptacle meaning fixed connector because for other reasons and this Jack is "Female" or S=Socket
- where P is for Plug, meaning moving connector.